# Web scraper crawler using Breadth First Search in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, nlp

I want to create web crawler for a wikipedia page( all the links within the page gets opened and saved too) which needs to be implemented in Breadth First Search way. I have been looking at a lot sources and stackoverflow codes/problems but unable to implement it.
I tried the following code :

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector

import time
start = time.time()

### Crawling to the website fetch links and images -> store images -> crawl more to the fetched links and scrape more images
all_images  = {} # website links as "keys" and images link as "values"
# GET request to recurship site
response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant')
selector = Selector(response.text)
href_links = selector.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
image_links = selector.xpath('//img/@src').getall()

for link in href_links:
    try:
        response = requests.get(link)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            image_links = selector.xpath('//img/@src').getall()
            all_images[link] = image_links
    except Exception as exp:
        print('Error navigating to link : ', link)





print(all_images)
end = time.time()
print("Time taken in seconds : ", (end-start))
```

but this throws an error saying "Error Navigating to link". How do I go about it ? I am a total newbie in this field.

Comment: Always good to print the error exception in those cases. ```print(exp)```

Answer (score 0):

Your href_links will be relative path for wiki links.

You must append the baseUrl of wikipedia.

```
base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'

href_links = [base_url + link for link in selector.xpath('//a/@href').getall()]
```

Note that this will work for wiki links if you have external links in href use something like this:

```
href_links = []
for link in selector.xpath('//a/@href').getall():
    if not link.startswith('http'):
        href_links.append(base_url + link)
    else:
        href_links.append(link)
```